# scalable inline-svg inside grid-item does not scale well

Tags: css, d3.js, inline-svg

[image]I made an inline svg with 3d.js and I want to use it in a grid layout.
Its using minmax(0,xfr) to make sure nothing gets bigger then the grid-item itself.
That works resonable but not with inline svg.
It seems to ignore the size at first, so I had to set the width and height.
But even that is ignored, when the screen becomes wide enough :(

Also it is not positioned in the middle but at the top so also the  justify-self: center;
align-self: center; options of the grid-item is totaly ignored.

I am trying for hours now with all kind of settings (like preserve aspect ratio etc) but they all seems to not work. Also transform does not seem to work in all screen resolutions.
It seems I do something completely wrong, the size is determent by the svg element while the grid should set the size and the svg should adapt.

How can I make this svg behave like a normal scalable picture/div ?
You can see the code in codepen :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="Picture"></div>
  <div class="Time">
    <div class="StopWatch">
        
    </div>
    <div class="MinutesText"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Level">
    <div class="LevelPicture" style=" width:100%; height:100%">
    
         <svg  viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="circleLevel">
       
   
   </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="LevelText"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Arrow">
     
  </div>
</div>



.container {  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 0.2fr) minmax(0, 1.5fr) minmax(0, 2.6fr) minmax(0, 0.6fr) minmax(0, 0.1fr);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 0.2fr) minmax(0, 1.3fr) minmax(0, 1.3fr) minmax(0, 0.2fr);
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    ". . . . ."
    ". Picture Time . ."
    ". Picture Level Arrow ."
    ". . . . .";
}

.Picture {
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  grid-area: Picture;
}

.Time {  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0,0.4fr) minmax(0,1.6fr);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0,1fr);
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "StopWatch MinutesText";
  grid-area: Time;
}

.StopWatch {
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  grid-area: StopWatch;
}

.MinutesText {
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: center;
  grid-area: MinutesText;
}

.Level {  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0,0.4fr) minmax(0,1.6fr);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0,1fr);
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "LevelPicture LevelText";
  grid-area: Level;
}

.LevelPicture {
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  grid-area: LevelPicture;
}

.LevelText {
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: center;
  grid-area: LevelText;
}

.Arrow {
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  grid-area: Arrow;
}


html, body , .container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/mistert007/pen/mdjRwqr?editors=1111

Comment: can you try 2 thing: 1) remove any width, height in the svg if any 2) instead of grid align, justify, put for the element align-self and justify-self center

Comment: I changed the svg element into:  <svg  viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="circleLevel"  style=" width:100%; height:100%;   justify-self: center;  align-self: center;">     </svg>    And now the scaling works !  It follows the size of the grid-elemt.  But can you explain what is the difference ?  Because to me it feels like magic ;)

Comment: put align self and justify self in the parent not the svg.

Comment: Yes I did but that did not seem to work

Comment: I tried to reproduce with your code, bit complicated! You are using grid, and nested grid with a lot (too much) properties everywhere. I'm not really understanding what final result you want. Could you have a drawing for me to understand?

Comment: I think it works now with the align-self and justify-self !     I attached a picture of the result I want, that the SVG is scaling exactly to the size of the grid-item size. Thanks for the help !  Before it was growing outside of the grid-item box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250944/discussion-between-mistert69-and-pier-farrugia).